# How to set the correct python path on Ubuntu

Tags: server, python

I'm trying to run a simple python program on ubuntu server 12.04. However I get an import error for a module I've written. The module folder has an **init**.py folder in however python does not seem to find it giving the following error

```
user1@cl:~/git/p1/test$ ls
  modules  prog1.py 
user1@cl:~/git/p1/test$ python prog1.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "prog1.py", line 8, in <module>
    from modules import find
ImportError: No module named modules
```

From reading associated question it would appear I need to set a python path. Could anyone tell me exactly what files I need to modify, I've seen suggestions including .bashrc .bash_profile and .profile. And also what directory I need to point the path too. I'm not totally sure if this should be my home directory or the exact folder my program is in, or the folder the module is in.

Sorry if this is a very basic question I'm new to ubuntu

Comment: Can you try renaming `modules` to something like `no_modules` and then change in your `prog1.py` and try again?

Comment: Is the `__init__.py` file empty? And hope `find` is name as `find.py`, is it?

Comment: Could you give us the tree structure of your "modules" directory please? and its location. You can use the `tree` command (after a `sudo apt-get install tree`)

Comment: To the on hold voters: I am not suggesting the question provides all information, however, what is missing seems to be about infirmation OP is asking for.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your question, I am not sure what is the precise situation, but to set a (any) path from a python program or script:

```
import sys
sys.path.insert(0, "/path/to/your/module(s)")
```

However, looking at the first two lines of your question, both the program and the `modules` folder are in the same directory, which makes setting the path unnecessary. It looks like there is someting wrong with your `__init__.py` file; you mention an "init.py" folder, but is there a (empty) file named `__init__.py` in it?

The modules structure should be:

```
modules (folder)
|___  __init__.py
|___  file1.py
|___  file2.py
```

etc.

to import:

```
from modules import file1, file2 (file1, 2 without extension)
```

Comment: @david I had a feeling it was something like that ;) Glad it worked out.

Answer (score 0):

You should first take a look at the python [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.2/tutorial/modules.html#packages) related to packages.

Now if you need to give the path to your module do it this way:

```
cd ~/git/p1/test
PYTHONPATH=/home/user1/ python ./prog1.py
```

Just replace `/home/user1/` with the full path to your home-made module.

Comment: Is that necessary if `modules` is in the same directory as the script? I have tried without it and it works without having to set `PYTHONPATH`.

Comment: @Jobin: modules in the same directory as the script will be automatically added to [sys.path](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/sys.html#sys.path)

Comment: Right, so what is the purpose of modifying `PYTHONPATH`?

Comment: I don't think the OP mentioned that the "modules" was in the same location as the prog1.py script